# Is there a way to populate a spreadsheet of city names with their latitudes and longitudes from Google Maps or some other service?

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, excel

I have a long list of cities in the United States, and would like to get the coordinates for each city without looking up each one individually. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572/latitude-longitude-database

Comment: +1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155918/list-of-major-cities-with-latitude-longitude-and-timezone

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org) and its free [web services](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html). The service you will most likely want to use is its [full text search service](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html).

Have a look at the documentation and examples and see how far you can get.

If you don't know how to use a web API, or know how to populate a spreadsheet, you might ask (or search first) at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386205/blah238). See also other questions on this site tagged [geonames](/questions/tagged/geonames).

Comment: This is the way to go, we use this to locate all of our aid projects.

Answer (score 2):

**GPS Visualizer's Easy Batch Geocoder can do this.**

> Geocode multiple addresses
>
> If you have a large batch of addresses for which you need coordinates,
>   GPS Visualizer's Multiple Address Locator is the solution. This form
>   allows you to geocode an large number of addresses using Yahoo or
>   Google's Geocoding API service. Your data can be in either a raw,
>   jumbled, unformatted list, or in a structured table with a header row;
>   output is plain text but can be plotted on a map or written to a GPX
>   file.
>
> How is works Google and Yahoo each provide a geocoding "API" -- a way
>   for other programs to quickly and easily access their services. But
>   they only allow a certain number of queries per day, based on your IP
>   address. This form uses JavaScript-On-Demand (JSON) code that causes
>   your Web browser to be the one making the request (rather than
>   gpsvisualizer.com), which means your queries don't count against my
>   server's limit. (And thanks are due to the developers of the batch
>   geocoder at BatchGeocode.com for the Yahoo JSON info.) Verifying
>   strange results Sometimes the geocoder returns coordinates that don't
>   seem right. Unfortunately, there's no way to get Yahoo's precision
>   information using this form -- but you can see Yahoo's precision
>   estimate for individual addresses

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/

Comment: This is the only service where I can drop a list of "town, country" vagueness and still get something generated from it.

Answer (score 2):

After spending some time looking for a quick and easy solution this is what I settled on. I hope someone else finds this useful. Using OpenStreetMap's python API, Nominatim is great for map queries by name. Here is the function I use.

```
from OSMPythonTools.nominatim import Nominatim

# Converts a iterable of string City names to a list of lat lon stings
# Example: Input - "New York, NY, USA"
#          Output = "40.7127281,-74.0060152"
def QueryLocations(city_names):
    nominatim = Nominatim()
    output = []
    for name in city_names:
        print(name)
        city_json = nominatim.query(name).toJSON()[0]
        output.append(city_json["lat"] + "," + city_json["lon"])
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

Google My Maps or Google Maps Engine possibly pro.   This converts named locations to gps coordinates to a KML file.

https://mapsengine.google.com/map/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Geocodio](https://geocod.io/upload/) to geocode a list of cities. You can paste them in, upload a spreadsheet, or use an API. Note that for the best results you'll want to include the state if you can.

Edit: I'm a co-founder of Geoocodio. Apologies for any confusion about that.

Comment: Does that work in India and other countries too? Failed when I made a request to get coordinates of a city from india

Answer (score 0):

Tried to register a google cloud accont in order to get the map api while using data from [simplemaps](https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities) will be easier and free of charges...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).